# what should be returned when calling "getpid() == fork()"

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf ("%d", getpid() == fork());
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is `00`. I don't quite understand why `0` is printed twice. My understanding it that after `fork()` is called, a child process is created. And now both processes continue running the next line of the program. Doesn't that mean the child process will run `return 0`? I can see that I will get `00` if it's `fork() == getpid()` tho. Thanks!

Comment: What you've written is the same as `i = fork(); printf("%d", getpid() == i)`.  The fork gets called before the printf, and the child calls printf.

Comment: I would advise against using fork in this manner.

Comment: A more interesting question is whether the LHS of `getpid() == fork()` is the pid of the parent or the child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Oog,yes, the evaluation order is indeterminate, I didn't even think of that. But the only process ID that `fork` returns is the child's process ID, and it returns that to the _parent_, so it can't compare equal to `getpid` in either process.

Comment: Why are such questions continually asked?  If there's doubt over some confusing statement/expression, rewite it in more steps so as to remove the confusion.

Comment: @MartinJames To find out what happens, I think.

Comment: @MartinJames Well because the professors like this kind of confusing questions.

Comment: We can just hope that the reason is to teach the students "Writing code like this will get you fired".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fork` does not cause the child process to jump to the "next line".  Assuming the operation succeeds, the `fork` *function call* returns twice, once in each process.  So both processes execute the comparison to `getpid`.

Also, the C standard doesn't specify whether the call to `getpid` happens before the call to `fork` (in which case it happens only once) or after (in which case it happens twice and returns two different values), but this turns out not to matter, because all of the possible situations lead to the comparison being false:

- `fork` fails: no new process is created and it returns −1 to the parent, which is not a valid process ID and therefore cannot compare equal to the value returned to the parent by `getpid`.  It doesn't matter whether the `getpid` happens before or after the `fork`, because it's the same process in either case.
- `fork` succeeds: it returns the child's process ID to the parent, and it returns zero to the child.

  - The child's process ID cannot be equal to the parent's process ID (because both of them are running at the same time), so, in the parent, the comparison will always be false, and it doesn't matter whether the `getpid` happens before or after the `fork` because it's the same process in either case.
  - If the `getpid` call happened before the `fork`, the child will compare zero to the parent's process ID; if it happened after the `fork`, the child will compare zero to the child's process ID.  Zero is not a valid process ID either, so the comparison will be false either way.

`getpid` is one of a very few system calls that POSIX says cannot ever fail, so we don't have to worry about that possibility.

Therefore, the only things this program can print are `0` (if `fork` fails) or `00` (if `fork` succeeds).

I would strongly recommend not writing anything like this in a real program.  Operations with "abnormal" control-flow behavior, like `fork`, should always be done as stand-alone statements, because this makes the program easier for humans to read.  You might not have realized yet just how important that is, so let me leave you with an exercise: reread a program that you wrote more than three months ago, and try to remember what it does and why.  (If you haven't been programming for long enough to do that, make a note to do this exercise when you can.)

Answer (score 5):

[fork documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

When `fork()` returns, in both parent and child processes - it returns immediately after the ending of the invocation of the `fork()` system call. It could well be in the middle of the line as is the case here - you return with a value for the expression `fork()` and use that value to continue evaluating the expression that contained it - in this case - a condition within a `printf`.

`fork()` returns the PID of the child process in the parent process or 0 in the child process (or -1 on error).

In this case, both processes have the condition `getpid() == fork()` return 0 (false) since in the parent, the `getpid()` is different from the value returned by `fork()` since it's the parent processes pid (not the child's) and in the child - the `fork` returns 0 which is an illegal PID and can't be returned by `getpid()`.

Thus the `00` output.

Comment: Okay, my question now is why the value of getpid() in child process is its own pid? Isn't getpid() called before fork() and child process copies everything from the parent process so that it has the same value as parent process?

Comment: It depends on the order of evaluation of the expression. It could well have been evaluated before the fork and contain the PID of the parent process, in that you are correct, but it still can't be 0 - which is what the `fork()` returns in the child process.